# Possible spammer

Tags: support

[haseen](https://superuser.com/users/285077/haseen) has posted 22 answers to Superuser, almost all of which link to kakasoft.com (and the rest linked to other low-quality sites). Many of his answers are blatantly wrong (e.g. claims to prevent copying but allow reading files [here](https://superuser.com/questions/406082/shared-folder-read-only-but-anti-copy/739470#739470) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/722868/protecting-files-from-the-network/722875#722875)).

I suspect this account is being used to spam superuser. It is certainly possible that the person is just confused and happens to be a strong supporter of kakasoft, mind you. I could not determine how to report this account other than via meta.superuser.com.

Comment: Good eye! This type of commercial promotion is definitely against the rules. Looks like the mods have already suspended him :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for bringing this up.

In the future, you may as well simply flag a post by the user and provide a custom flag reason, pointing out the problem.

Comment: Thanks, will do.